# Testing My MapActivity with robolectric

Tags: android, google-maps, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to test using robolectric and getting the error below. Seems like other people have received this error when adding an Intent after create() but I'm not doing manipulating the intent at all. Maybe I need to do something special for this because it uses fragments, but that's just a guess. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:4967)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:90)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:114)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:123)
    at com.LocationsResultsMapTest.setUp(LocationsResultsMapTest.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

LocationsResultsMapTest.java

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LocationsResultsMapTest {

    private MockMapActivity activity;
    private ActivityController<MockMapActivity> activityController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MockMapActivity.class);
        activity = activityController.create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

MockMapActivity.java

```
public class MockMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/972).

Here is my current workaround:

Create your custom shadow (for example ShadowMapActivityWorkaround) from the ShadowMapActivity (get it from robolectric sources)

Make the following changes:

```
public void __constructor__() {
    super.__constructor__();
}
```

and

```
@Implementation
public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(connectivityBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter());
    field("mCalled").ofType(boolean.class).in(realActivity).set(true);
}
```

add the shadow to org.robolectric.Config.properties for example:

```
shadows: com.mytests.shadows.ShadowMapActivityWorkaround
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to implement what you were saying, but I'm still getting the same error. Here is my updated code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9120783

Comment: Erik, do not extend ShadowMapActivity in your custom shadow , because in this case the call of super.__constructor__(); in your shadow will not have any effect. In ShadowMapActivity this method just blank. Take code from here https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowMapActivity.java rename class name and add changes.